# Selenium: how to understand which element to send keys to?

Tags: python, selenium

Keep bumping into the same problem: when I use Selenium (Python), I often need to find the element to send_keys() to. E.g. on ebay front webpage, need to search for some item.

Each time I end up tring all the classes/frames around what I need (sometimes with ChroPath) and one of them works. Is there a simpler and more systematic way to find the element corresponding to search tab to send keys to?

Comment: by name is usually best for input fields.  Ex: for search field here, use By.name('q') (for python, "find_element_by_name('q')"

Comment: @pcalkins Sorry, I don't understand. What do you search for?

Comment: sorry, should have been more clear, that's for the search field here at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing you could try is using `hasattr` method to check if the element has a particular attribute or not. From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) about `hasattr`

> hasattr(object, name) The arguments are an object and a string. The
>   result is True if the string is the name of one of the object’s
>   attributes, False if not. (This is implemented by calling
>   getattr(object, name) and seeing whether it raises an AttributeError
>   or not.)

```
if hasattr(element, 'send_keys'):
    # do something
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried a candidate - it returns True on has_attr(element, 'send_keys), but then I get the usual error: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <div class="home-page-search"> is not reachable by keyboard

Comment: well thats a new error which for me is progress, take a look at this question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864965/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-reachable-by

Comment: also as the answer does get you forward in your problem, can you mark it as correct?

Comment: The link to the other discussion is pretty useful though

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you shouldn't try to invoke `send_keys()` on random elements on a webpage, e.g. *ebay homepage*.

Ideally, the [WebElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) with whom you would interact or invoke `send_keys()` should be part of your tests and should also be a part of the *Test Plan*.

While you execute your tests, in the due coarse you may encounter different errors when `send_keys()` is being invoked. You have a to address the issues as they show up as per the prevailing condition of the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on `send_keys()` in:

- [How to insert a value in a field Text using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59723725/how-to-insert-a-value-in-a-field-text-using-selenium/59723783#59723783)
- [Using Selenium in Python to enter currency format text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120558/using-selenium-in-python-to-enter-currency-format-text/54120840#54120840)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's an issue with waiting. In my case there's embedded javascript, so I need to handle that.

Comment: @LazyCat I didn't speak about waits here in this discussion yet :) However the examples I have provided as reference may include waits as a solution. My answer is pretty generic with respect to _which element to send keys to_